# left/right page dependent formatting

Tags: css

I'm trying to find a way to float certain items left on left-hand pages, and right and right-hand pages. Not sure where to look, since all I can find that seems related is @page :left/:right, but that seems to only apply to the page box and margins, not the page content.

Here's an example of what I want to do; The first float wants to go to the right, if it is on page 1, and the second float wants to go to the left, if it is on page 2, but to the right if it is on page 3.

The big boxes are just meant to demonstrate that there could be a lot (particularly an unknown) of stuff between the floats, and I can't predict which page might contain the float. (Thanks to Christian for making the assumption that I could, to point out the unstated assumption in my question, and I could make this clarifying edit.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>float left or right</title>
        <link href=favicon-index.ico type=image/x-icon rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href=/style.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
        <style>
          div { border: solid black 1px; }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>float left or right</h1>
        <div style="page-break-inside: autor;">
          <div style="float: right;">
            float 1 content
          </div>
          page 1 content
          <div style="height: 8in; width: 1in;"></div>
          unknown amount of content between floats
          <div style="height: 8in; width: 1in;"></div>
          <div style="float: right;">
            float content somewhere later
          </div>
          <div>content winds up on page 2? 3? 4? 5?</div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

But how do I instruct the browser to do that?

N.B. At least in 2001, the "Complete Idiots Guide" series of books used this sort of odd/even dependent float for the sidebars entitled "Learning Links" (and maybe other such sidebars also). So there is precedent for this sort of style requirement, although I'm not trying to reproduce their books in HTML!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your query

If you change your html structure as given in the code below then apply the following CSS, then your query will be satisfied

```css
.pages div:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>float left or right</title>
  <link href=favicon-index.ico type=image/x-icon rel="shortcut icon">
  <link href=/style.css type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
  <style>
    div {
      border: solid black 1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>float left or right</h1>
  <div class="pages">
    <div id="page-1">page 1 content</div>
    <div id="page-2">page 2 content</div>
    <div id="page-3">page 3 content</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The structure is not changed much but it's almost similar to the one you provided

Comment: @Christian you make the assumption that I know where the page boundaries are. If I knew that, yes, your scheme would work. My tall boxes were just meant to be "large filler to demonstrate that it might take more than one or two pages.